# pipes giving continuous output after execvp

Tags: pipe, fork, execvp

I'm currently working on a project where I have to create a unix shell. I am having problems with my function where I where execute commands like "ls" or "wc". My code executes the execvp and pipes it to the output correctly but after that, it keeps entering an empty input and the only way I can stop it is by manually exiting the program. I thought it had to do with me not closing the pipes in the correct order so I closed them in all sorts of order but I'm still having the same problem no matter what I do.

**Function executing command**

```
void singleCommand(vector<string> vcommands) {
  // turn commands into char
  char* command[vcommands.size()+1];
  for(int i=0; i<vcommands.size(); i++){
     command[i] = (char*)vcommands.at(i).c_str();
  }
  command[vcommands.size()] = NULL;

  int p[2];
  pipe(p);

  int pid = fork();
  if(pid == -1){ // verifying fork was created
    printf("Error: fork was unsuccessful, Terminating");
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  if(pid == 0){ //pid returns a zero when a new child process is created.
    close(p[0]);
    dup2(p[1],1);
    close(p[1]);
    execvp (command[0],command);
    exit(1);
  } else if (pid > 0) {//pid is greater than zero we are in the parent
    wait(0);
    close(p[1]);
    dup2(p[0],0); // get stdin from pipe
    close(p[0]);
    char buff[1000]={0};

    read(STDIN_FILENO,buff,250);
    printf("%s",buff);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I thought it had to do with me not closing the pipes in the correct order so I closed them in all sorts of order but I'm still having the same problem no matter what I do

One obvious problem is that, in the parent process, you are closing the write end of the pipe, and reading the other end, only *after* a call to `wait()`. What does this call do? It waits for the child to finish.

Do you really want to read the pipe only after the child has died ? This is not how a shell works and this may only bring you issues because the capacity of a pipe is not infinite: if it is full, the writer (the child) will block until it can write again into the pipe, which will never happen since the only reader is waiting for the end of the child.